# Symfony-Finder cant open dir

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-finder

I try to read the dir and wanna get the last files from the current date.

When I put the url in the browser I got a result of all the files, which are in the ftp-directory.

So I have the proof, that the ftp-connectionparameter still works.

[image]

When I try to start the following function, then I get the error

> RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(ftp://...@example.com:4242): failed to open dir: operation failed

Here is the Exception from symfony:

[image]

```
/**
 * @Route("/download", name="getfile")
 */
public function getFileWithFtp()
{

    $host = "example.com";
    $username = "username";
    $userpass = "userpass";
    $port = 4242;


    $url = 'ftp://' . $username . ':' . $userpass . '@' . $host . ':' . $port .'/';
    $datum = date('Y-m-d');

    $finder = new Finder();
    $iterator = $finder
        ->files()
        ->in($url)
        ->name('*BEHWN.TXT')
        ->date($datum);

    $anzahl = count($iterator);

    return $this->render('ftp/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'FtpController',
        'url' => $url,
        'anzahl' => $anzahl
    ]);
}
```

WHen i open the url with the file with file_gets_content($url."filename.txt"), then i get the content without error.

Only it seems that I dont use the Finder from Symfony not correct.

My current Symfony is 4.1.4 and I had cleared the caches and also i deleted the cache-files manually.

Thanks for every tipp

Here is the link to the symfony-finder-component:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html

As the Finder uses PHP iterators, you can pass any URL with a supported protocol:

Here is the part of the FTP code from the documentation:

```
// always add a trailing slash when looking for in the FTP root dir
$finder->in('ftp://example.com/');

// you can also look for in a FTP directory
$finder->in('ftp://example.com/pub/');
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs, what you have in $iterator is a PHP [iterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php),
so you need to use [iterator_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-count.php):

```
$anzahl =  iterator_count($iterator);
```

Comment: It would not work, I got the same error: 
  
 RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(ftp://...@example.com:4242): failed to open dir:

Answer (score 0):

This WILL not work anymore IF you are using symfony v3.4.7 and above..

There is the issue:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27423

I did a fix but it will take a while till it gets merged i think
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/28604

Summary:

"In Finder[...]was released which should remove duplicate slashes from path names.
However, this results in an error when used to find files in an FTP root dir."

"As a result, a working code before v3.4.7 result in breaking code after v3.4.7"

This is the method messing things up, including my fix
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/0670c48477b3d88787b6fe0dec168c5c8ae49c66/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder.php#L741